# Creating messenger Inkwell

Tags: flutter, messenger

I was creating Inkwell in flutter, but that is not the same as the messenger. can anyone please create this for me in flutter?

[image]

what I create was too fast.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like a slower ripple effect, then you have to change splashFactory property in your MaterialApp theme from InkSplash.splashFactory (default) to InkRipple.splashFactory. InkRipple's splash looks more like native.

Comment: I used  InkRipple.splashFactory, but still, inkwell is not slow as much as the messenger inkwell.  that is still fast. do you have any other idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party package splash alternatives from https://pub.dev/packages/splash/example . WaveSplash from that package maybe helpful for your need

```
WaveSplash.customSplashFactory(strokeWidth: 30, blurStrength: 5)
```

just play around with those figures.

Remember to import the package:

```
import 'package:splash/splash.dart';
```